# Setting the background image to html button?

Tags: css, html

I have below code to set the background image to button.

### CSS:

```
input.hButton{
    background-image: url('images/hbutton.png');
    height: 21px;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #696969;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    display:block;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="hButton" id="customize" value="Customize Table"></input>
```

### Output:

[image]

Here when the button text is too long, button is split. How can I get it fixed?

Comment: please remove your width or set it to auto

Comment: You should split your bg image in 2 parts. this link will help you : http://odyniec.net/articles/css-based-tabbed-menu/

Comment: you can use `CSS3`'s `background-size` property for this. check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Ganesh, i set it to auto.Still same problem.

Comment: @user755806 It really depends what your image looks like.Using `background-size: 100% 100%;` should take up the whole `input`.

Comment: Ruddy, the image is PNG image with dimensions 78 x 21.

Answer (score 2):

Add
background-size: 100% 100%;

or find your perfect setting here:
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Btw in your case should be better:

```
 use a gradient
 use border-radius for the upper corners
 use a thin border
```

Comment: user1229017, i gave background-size: 100% 100%; . but still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

replace your css code background-image property with this one :

background-image: url('images/hbutton.png') top repeat-y;

Comment: Tushar, when i gave as u specified, it could not find out the image itself.. i am getting normal button.

Comment: your image width might be smaller than the width of that butoon contents..."Customize table" ... you can manuall change the width of ur image.. i think this this will help you...

Comment: How can i increase the width of image?

Comment: relace this 
background-image: url('images/hbutton.png') top repeat-y;

with this new one:
background-image: url('images/hbutton.png') top left repeat;   or 
background-image: url('images/hbutton.png') center center no-repeat/repeat;

Comment: you can increase the width of image with opening that image using microsoft office picture manager ---> click on edit pictures ---> and increase width as per requirement...try this one last time...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48022/discussion-between-tusharg-and-user755806)

Answer (score 1):

Hi please use the pure css code.. and remove your older method..

Fiddle:http:http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/RZ4vV/1/

### What's Here?

1-Gradient

2-Border radius

3.border top,right and left

```
.hButton{

    border:solid 1px #0e4f85;
    border-bottom:none;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    padding:3px;
    color:#696969;
    background: #f7f5f5; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f5f5 0%, #e0dede 50%, #e0dede 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f7f5f5), color-stop(50%,#e0dede), color-stop(99%,#e0dede)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f5f5 0%,#e0dede 50%,#e0dede 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f5f5 0%,#e0dede 50%,#e0dede 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f5f5 0%,#e0dede 50%,#e0dede 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f7f5f5 0%,#e0dede 50%,#e0dede 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f5f5', endColorstr='#e0dede',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    }
```

Comment: Nikhil, it does not give me same look and feel like my button picture.

Comment: @user755806,little color variation are here...plz check the latest fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/RZ4vV/2/

Comment: Nikhil, this is working in FF but border radius is not working in IE10

Comment: use @ border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:0px;border-bottom-right-radius:0px; :)